# Reordering KOMA-Script title (not titlepage) in custom class

Tags: titles, koma-script, etoolbox

I'm trying to define custom styles for the KOMA-Script title which is later inserted using the `\maketitle` command currently using a mix of the KOMA-Script `\setkomafont` command and the `\patchcmd` command from the `etoolbox` package.

To clear up any confusion, here's a short **mwe.cls**:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{mwe}[2015/12/07 mwe0.1]
\LoadClass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}

\ProcessOptions\relax

\setkomafont{subject}{\normalfont}
\setkomafont{title}{\normalfont\scshape}
\setkomafont{subtitle}{\normalfont}
\setkomafont{author}{\normalfont}
\setkomafont{date}{\normalfont}

\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\huge}{\fontsize{32}{36}\selectfont}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\@title}{\vspace{-18pt}\@title{}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\@subtitle}{\@subtitle{} \\ \@@subject{}}{}{} % this line apparently does not have any effect
%\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\@subject}{}{}{} % if this line is commented out, the subject is hidden, not appended to the subtitle

\endinput
```

And the corresponding **mwe.tex**:

```
\documentclass{mwe}

\subject{Subject}
\title{Title}
\subtitle{Subtitle}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

Further content...
\end{document}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is that the subject is displayed after the subtitle - I'm not using `\publisher` or another built-in title command as a workaround to stay semantically correct.

To me it appears like patching the subtitle command does not succeed, probably because of a different internal processing name for the command, but I didn't find anything about it in the KOMA-Script documentation.

Comment: `\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\@subtitle}{\@subtitle{} \\ \@@subject{}}{\typeout{OK!}}{\typeout{Oh, no!}}` will tell you for sure....

Comment: `...("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\misc\etex.sty"
Package: etex 2015/09/02 v2.4 eTeX basic definition package (PEB,DPC)
\et@xins=\count88
)
\etb@tempcnta=\count89
)
OK!
)...`

Apparently, the hook somehow works. The changes just don't make it into the document.

Comment: They do. They do exactly what you asked TeX to do. They just don't do what I think you think you asked TeX to do. This is probably because TeX is a computer programme and I am a human being, so I can guess that you didn't really want what you asked for whereas TeX blithely assumes that you intended exactly that. ;)

Comment: I don't think patching is the right thing to do here. Just define `\@maketitle` the way you want the title to appear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The patch is applied. Here is the line which your patch affects (from `scrartcl.cls`):

```
{\ifx\@subtitle\@empty\else\usekomafont{subtitle}\@subtitle\par\fi}%
```

So you will end up with

```
{\ifx\@subtitle{} \\ \@@subject{}\@empty\else\usekomafont{subtitle}\@subtitle\par\fi}%
```

which means that the `\ifx` conditional fails, so `\@@subject{}` etc. is never executed (because you told it to use this only if the test succeeded). So the `\else` bit is executed, which is identical to the original code.

You need to be more specific about what you want patched and where:

```
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\usekomafont{subtitle}\@subtitle\par\fi}{%
  {\usekomafont{subtitle}\@subtitle\par}\fi
  \vskip .5em
  {\ifx\@subject\@empty\else\usekomafont{subject}\@subject\par}\fi}{\typeout{OK!}}{\typeout{Oh, no!}} % this line apparently does not have any effect
```

Note that it is very important to use `\par` here. It *may* be that `\\` is translated to a paragraph ending anyway, but it may not be. And you want a paragraph break to ensure correct vertical spacing and to avoid bad boxes. Since different parts of the title use different fonts and font sizes, the vertical spacing will be incorrect if you use a line break instead.

[image: Subject below]

Code:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.cls}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{\jobname}[2015/12/07 \jobname0.1]
\LoadClass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}

\ProcessOptions\relax

\setkomafont{subject}{\normalfont}
\setkomafont{title}{\normalfont\scshape}
\setkomafont{subtitle}{\normalfont}
\setkomafont{author}{\normalfont}
\setkomafont{date}{\normalfont}

\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\huge}{\fontsize{32}{36}\selectfont}{\typeout{OK! Title size changed!}}{\typeout{Oh, no! Title still huge!}}
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\@title}{\vspace{-18pt}\@title{}}{\typeout{OK! Moving up!}}{\typeout{Oh, no! Stuck down here!}}
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\@subject}{}{\typeout{OK! Subject eliminated!}}{\typeout{Oh, no! Subject persists!}}
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\usekomafont{subtitle}\@subtitle\par\fi}{%
  {\usekomafont{subtitle}\@subtitle\par}\fi
  \vskip .5em
  {\ifx\@subject\@empty\else\usekomafont{subject}\@subject\par}\fi}{\typeout{OK! Subject added!}}{\typeout{Oh, no! Could not add subject!}}

\endinput
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{\jobname}
\subject{Subject}
\title{Title}
\subtitle{Subtitle}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Further content\dots
\end{document}
```

Note that the use of the last two arguments in `\patchcmd` provides useful diagnostics. Each one should tell you what has been tried and whether it succeeded or not. If you use a common prefix (`OK!` or `Oh, no!`) then you can search the `.log` file for all successes or failures. For example `grep OK <jobname>.log` gives me

```
OK! Title size changed!
OK! Moving up!
OK! Subject eliminated!
OK! Subject added!
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed answer. Nice not only to know how this works correctly, but why it didn't work before. I've also learned a bit more about the usage of `\patchcmd` - I knew it worked using substitution before, but apparently not exactly like I've imagined. 

I think you grabbed the relevant code from a file - may I ask which? I've tried browsing through the KOMA-Script files myself, but they're huge and I didn't succeed in finding anything relevant, neither in the files nor in the documentation.

Comment: I just looked in `scrartcl.cls` since that was what you were using and searched for e.g. `@maketitle` or `@subtitle` etc. Thanks for reminding me - I forgot the reference but have added it now.